# Nestjs can't resolve dependencies of the AppService (EventEmitter, ?) error

Tags: javascript, nestjs

after installing this packages:

```
$ npm install --save @nestjs/schedule
$ npm install --save-dev @types/cron

$ npm i --save @nestjs/event-emitter
```

and updating`AppServie` to them:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {EventEmitter2, OnEvent} from '@nestjs/event-emitter';
import {ScheduleRegistry, Cron, CronExpression} from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(
        private readonly eventEmitter: EventEmitter2,
        private scheduleRegistry: ScheduleRegistry,
        ) {
    }

    @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
    sendNotificationScheduler() {
        console.log('+++++++ HELLO++++++++');
    }
}
```

and updating `AppModule`:

```js
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ConfigModule} from '@nestjs/config';
import {EventEmitterModule} from '@nestjs/event-emitter';
import {ScheduleModule} from '@nestjs/schedule';
import {AppService} from './app.service';


@Module({
    imports: [
        EventEmitterModule.forRoot(),
        ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    providers: [
        AppService
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

unfortunately i get this error:

```
[Nest] 308  - 07/05/2023, 9:16:53 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppService (EventEmitter, ?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [1] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
 - Is AppModule a valid NestJS module?
 - If Object is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
 - If Object is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
   @Module({
     imports: [ /* the Module containing Object */ ]
   })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppService (EventEmitter, ?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [1] is available in the AppModule context.
```

Comment: why are you using `ScheduleRegistry` as a provider? I that believe it is just an interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you missed on what you could inject into your providers.

I believe that it should be `SchedulerRegistry`, not `ScheduleRegistry`. See https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#dynamic-timeouts

[image: docs]

Comment: oh thank you very much, I'm so sorry